# i want to send multiple files to web api from angular2

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api controller like below .* note: i took out the code inside.

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        public string SimilarFaces(IFormCollection files, IFormFile file)
        {

        }
```

Now i have an angular2 post request where i am trying to send a set of data, one which is a form data containing multiple files and another which is a form data containing a single file. This is my first time using web api and angular2 together, so i'm not sure how to make my post request match what the controller is looking for. please find below my http post code.

```
 similarity(files: any,file:any): Promise<any>
  {
      return this.http.post(this.serverUrl + "face/similarfaces/",data,{headers:headers})
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => response.json())
          .catch(error => error);
  }
```

The parameter 'data' is where i know to put the data i'm sending, but i don't know how to set it properly so the web api understands what i'm sending to it. i want to send both files and file in that single request.

Answer (score 0):

you have to send you data in JSON format .

```
similarit(filesOne, fileTwo){

var url = this.serverUrl + "face/similarfaces/"; 
var data = { filesOne: filesOne, fileTwo: fileTwo };
var headers = { headers:headers }

return $http.post(url, data, headers)
    .then(function(response){
        return response.data
    });
}
```